# SQLAlchemy relationship() via intermediary table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I am struggling to define methods in SQLAlchemy to retrieve related records via an intermediary table.

Consider the following schema:

- Users can create multiple posts, each post belongs to 1 user
- Each post can have multiple comments on it, with each comment belonging to 1 post

What I want is to be able to, for a given user instance, retrieve *all* of the comments from *all* of their posts.

I have set this up as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)

# define model classes
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    posts: Mapped[list["Post"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"(<{__class__.__name__}> name: {self.name})"


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="posts")

    comments: Mapped[list["Comment"]] = relationship(back_populates="post")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"(<{__class__.__name__}> title: {self.title})"


class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = "comments"

    body: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    post_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("posts.id"))
    post: Mapped["Post"] = relationship(back_populates="comments")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"(<{__class__.__name__}> body: {self.body})"
```

If I create a few instances of these models, you can see how things are related:

```py
# create instances
user = User(name="greta")

post_1 = Post(title="First post", user=user)
post_2 = Post(title="Second post", user=user)

comment_1 = Comment(body="yeah wotever", post=post_1)
comment_2 = Comment(body="lol good one", post=post_1)
comment_3 = Comment(body="lmfao", post=post_2)

# show all posts, and their comments
print(user)
for post in user.posts:
    print(f"   └── {post}")
    for comment in post.comments:
        print(f"          └── {comment}")
```

```
(<User> name: greta)
   └── (<Post> title: First post)
          └── (<Comment> body: yeah wotever)
          └── (<Comment> body: lol good one)
   └── (<Post> title: Second post)
          └── (<Comment> body: lmfao)
```

I am unsure of how to use `relationship()` to define a method `all_comments()` in the `User` class, which would return a list of all of the comments across all of a `user` instance's `posts`.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your secondary table `posts`, you can use `secondaryjoin` and `primaryjoin` in `relationship` to get what you want.

This way you needn't create a method `all_comments`, you can just do `user.comments` and get the comments, <strike>also the other way round, `comment.user` gives you the user.</strike> (see edit)

You probably want to tweak the join conditions, from my rudimentary testing this seems to get where you want to be.

I have created two users, which different set of posts and comments so you can see the difference.

```
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, Session


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    posts: Mapped[list["Post"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")

    comments: Mapped[list["Comment"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="user",
        secondary="posts",
        primaryjoin="User.id == Post.user_id",
        secondaryjoin="Comment.post_id == Post.id",
        viewonly=True,
    )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"(<{__class__.__name__}> name: {self.name})"


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = "posts"

    title: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="posts")

    comments: Mapped[list["Comment"]] = relationship(back_populates="post")

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"(<{__class__.__name__}> title: {self.title})"


class Comment(Base):
    __tablename__ = "comments"

    body: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()

    post_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("posts.id"))
    post: Mapped["Post"] = relationship(back_populates="comments")

    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(
        back_populates="comments",
        secondary="posts",
        primaryjoin="User.id == Post.user_id",
        secondaryjoin="Comment.post_id == Post.id",
        viewonly=True,
        uselist=False,
    )

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"(<{__class__.__name__}> body: {self.body})"


engine = create_engine("sqlite:///temp.db")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    user = User(name="greta")

    post_1 = Post(title="First post", user=user)
    post_2 = Post(title="Second post", user=user)

    comment_1 = Comment(body="yeah wotever", post=post_1)
    comment_2 = Comment(body="lol good one", post=post_1)
    comment_3 = Comment(body="lmfao", post=post_2)

    session.add_all((user, post_1, post_2, comment_1, comment_2, comment_3))

    user = User(name="not greta")

    post_1 = Post(title="Third post", user=user)
    post_2 = Post(title="Fourth post", user=user)

    comment_1 = Comment(body="wotever", post=post_1)
    comment_2 = Comment(body="good one", post=post_1)

    session.add_all((user, post_1, post_2, comment_1, comment_2))


with Session(engine) as session:
    statement = select(User)

    for user in session.scalars(statement):
        print(user, user.comments)
```

Output

```
(<User> name: greta) [(<Comment> body: yeah wotever), (<Comment> body: lol good one), (<Comment> body: lmfao)]
(<User> name: not greta) [(<Comment> body: wotever), (<Comment> body: good one)]
```

Edit: The reverse relation "get user from a comment" seems to be bugged in this implementation, one comment has more than one user, I am not sure where I went wrong, but if all you want is the relation "get all comments for a user" then this works.

Comment: This works perfectly. The user method is not bugged - in the context of the question I asked, the `user` of a comment is the author of the post on which the comment was made, rather than the user who posted the comment. Interestingly, the relation only works when the objects are committed to the database.

Comment: @g_t_m thanks for the feedback, I will have to understand why its not bugged though lol, and yeah it only works if its committed, the reason as per my understanding is that, the join relation works on id's and the id's are only generated if they are committed

Comment: actually I might be wrong here and do not want to mislead you @g_t_m (with regards to the relation working only after a commit)

Comment: fwiw, I tested it, you can use `session.flush()` to force the id's to get generated which in turn makes the relation work or executing the `select(User)` statement (within the context of the same session) makes sqlalchemy flush automatically and make the relation work, in either of these cases the commit was not needed